# Bug with Animation on Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

this is quite difficult to explain, but here we go!

Ok, the transition until I get the Fragment where the Animation is placed would be:

MainActivity (extends Activity) -> loginActivity (extendsActivity) -> now I call:

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(loginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("risposta",(Serializable)risposta);
homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // read below (StackOverFlow)
homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); // read below (StackOverFlow)
homeIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

which starts **HomeActivity** which extends **FragmentActivity** and at the end of `onCreateView()` I add my Fragment *CircleFragment* that `@Override`s this on `onResume()`:

```
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotateAnimation1.setDuration(4000);
    rotateAnimation1.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    radar.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);
```

or XML (tried both):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="0"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
  android:toDegrees="360"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="25%"
  android:duration="4000"
  android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

**WHAT HAPPENS?**

***SOMETIMES*** it works bad (sometimes fine!): it starts arround ~(50%, 25%) (or 0.5, 0.25), not exactly (calculated) but if I let the screen go off and I resume it, everything works again :O

**WHY IS IT STRANGE?**

1. do you see the two lines commented which cleans the task and start the activity on top ?
   if I don't set that, everything is OK
2. If I start it as MainActivity -> HomeActivity and doing finish (instead clearing tasks), it works as well fine.

What's happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the radar object?

Comment: it's a View, in this case, an ImageView

Comment: You're starting an Activity, which contains a Fragment. Then the `Fragment` wants to animate a view, is this correct?

Comment: yes, correct. I start animating on `onResume` of the Fragment

Answer (score 2):

When you hear statements like: "*SOMETIMES it works bad*", don't underestimate that. It basically means that there's probably a time component involved. Since the order of execution of multithreading operations is not necessarily known, thinks may happen a few milliseconds before or after and/or during different CPU/GPU Loads. At the same time, a few milliseconds earlier may mean that something else is still not finished, something we may need to be finished or that it may be "intensive".

With the Android Activity/Fragment lifecycle, thinks are "more or less" guaranteed to occur in certain order.

If you add **sometimes** + **more or less**, you've got a recipe for *unknownness*…

I haven't tried your particular scenario but I'd recommend the following steps:

1. Don't animate unless your layout has been laid out. You have to wait.
2. Don't animate unless your view has been created. You simple can't :D

So even if "sometimes works fine" I suspect that your sometimes is because you're animating too early when the view is not finished. Don't confuse the already confusing method name of `onCreatedView` with "Yeah, the view is created and laid out.". Created != Laid out.

So When is the view Laid out then?

When Android ends up doing a lot of measurement and drawing.

How do we know?

By using the ugliest piece of code you will see today…

Example (in your Fragment):

```
private volatile boolean mRootLayoutComplete = false; //just a global flag to let the Fragment know when we've been through this.

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
    // add a GlobalLayoutListener to hear back from the Layout engine.
    rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // This beauty can be thanked to Android for changing the name of the method.
            // In any case, you must unsusbcribe to this immediately.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
            // Mark this on a volatile global variable in case you want to use it elsewhere.
            mRootLayoutComplete = true;

            // Now you can ask: Is my view Created and not yet animated? 
            if ( mViewHasBeenCreated && !mRadarHasBeenAnimated ) {
                animate(mRadar); // call a method that will do the animation
            }
        };
    } // some {} may be wrong, I did it in this text editor :D
```

Now you need to flag that mViewHasBeenCreated… or you could check if `mRadar != null` instead of just using a semaphore.

To continue with my example…

```
// Define this flag too, because things are asynchronous we don't know who's gonna happen first!
private volatile boolean mViewHasBeenCreated = false;
```

In your:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mViewHasBeenCreated = true;
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

In your onResume:

```
boolean mRadarHasBeenAnimated = false; //flag to avoid multiple animations.

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if ( mRootLayoutComplete && mViewHasBeenCreated && !mRadarHasBeenAnimated ) {
        animate(mRadar); // could also check for null here
    }   
}
```

And the animate:

```
void animate(final View view) {
    if ( view == null ) {
       return;
    }
    // your animation code
    view.animate(youranimation);
    mRadarHasBeenAnimated = true;
}
```

Finally, if you want to animate "radar" every time you do onResume, then you must reset this…

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mRadarHasBeenAnimated = false;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Basically you're animating your view only after certain conditions have been met (notably the mRootLayoutComplete) and all the flags are to avoid running it multiple times, especially during CREATION. Since you don't know which is going to happen first, you need to "wait" and do it only when you're sure you can.

Good luck!

p.d.: I haven't tested the above code as it is, but I've used this trick in quite a few apps and it has always worked.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it was a wise answer.

I've tried that and it didn't work :\

But from your answer, I thought about not setting the ImageView, and I created, I set it as params: MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT and then animate it.

Neither worked. It doesn't have sense, if I set the Animation at 50% pivot and I animate it after adding the view to the container, it should work.